# What is the explanation for this inconsistent behavior related to document.domain and CORS?

Tags: javascript, cors

There seems to be a slight inconsistency with access restrictions when using `document.domain` to allow for CORS. Namely, changing the document domain from A to B continues to allow cross-origin requests to A, but **does not** allow access to iframes belonging to A.

Consider the following example:

```
<!-- b.html -->
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
</html>

<!-- test.domain.com/a.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      window.onload = function(e) {
        document.domain = "domain.com";
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        iframe.onload = function(e) {
          // This produces an access-denied error
          console.log(iframe.contentWindow.location.href);
        };

        $.ajax({url: "test.domain.com/b.html", success: function(result){
          console.log(result); // Will dump all of b.html 
        }});
      };
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

This situation seems weird to me. Once `document.domain`  is changed, access to an iframe containing `b.html` is restricted, but an ajax call to the same document is not. Is there a reason for this inconsistency? That is, why does the browser only consider `document.domain` when access child frames even in cases where the browser "knows" both child and parent frames came from the same origin?

Answer (score 2):

`document.domain` affects the `domain` part of an origin per the HTML Standard: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#dom-document-domain.

Then, some operations use "same origin" comparison and some operation use "same origin-domain" comparison. See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#same-origin.

The latter is only used for certain legacy scenarios as `document.domain` is a rather unwanted part of the web these days. Therefore, you will find these little inconsistencies.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why `document.domain` is unwanted? It seems like it is fairly useful way of connecting data from different subdomains, e.g. `facebook.com` and `api.facebook.com`. Is the thought that only `postMessage` should be used?

Comment: Yes. By using `document.domain` you open yourself up to attacks. If one subdomain gets compromised, so do you. If someone deploys a test on a subdomain without knowing about this, they also expose everyone else, etc. Maintaining origin-isolation is a good way to scope your potential attack vectors.